# Rails - Create/Destroy record in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, insert

I'm working on this record insert/delete I'm not sure what the syntax is to perform the query.

I have a user model and an event model.  I have created a joining table called Personal that stores the user_id, and event_id of any events that the users like.

I created an "Add" method in my events controller so whenever someone clicks it run to that and perform the create logic I'm trying to develop now.The action is tied to a extra column I added to the grid displaying all the events.

The user model =>

```
 has_many :personals
```

The event model =>

```
has_many :personals
```

The personal model =>

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :events
```

I thought it would be something like =>

```
 @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
 @event = Event.find(params[:id])
 # Personal.new = User.Event?
```

can anyone help?

Comment: Pls provide more information. What is the error msg? What is happening that you don't want or not happening that you do want?

One issue I see: are you sure that the session has been loaded with the user_id? Also, check your logs to see what the incoming params are to your controller action

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code for your `User`, `Event` and `Personal` models that shows the relationships between them.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining the situation better, I updated the question and would appreciate any help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, which would be unfortunate, removing the associated links can be tricky as there's no identifier for each link.

Using a `has_many :through` relationship is much easier to maintain and will allow you to do simple things like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :events,
    :through => :user_events
end

@user.events.delete(@event)
```

This doesn't remove the Event itself, that'd require an `Event#destroy` call, but the join record that links the two.

Comment: at least in rails `5.2.3` (ruby `2.6.3`), you can add and remove using `@user.events.push(@event)` and `@user.events.delete(@event)` when using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association

Comment: @AryehBeitz Over the years `has_many :through` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` have become a lot more similar. The HABTM approach is still not as consistent, though.